# Node module wallet adapter react problem

Tags: web3.js

I just imported these lines of code

```
import {
  ConnectionProvider,
  WalletProvider,
} from "@solana/wallet-adapter-react";
import { WalletAdapterNetwork } from "@solana/wallet-adapter-base";
import { UnsafeBurnerWalletAdapter } from "@solana/wallet-adapter-wallets";
import {
  WalletModalProvider,
  WalletDisconnectButton,
  WalletMultiButton,
} from "@solana/wallet-adapter-react-ui";
import { clusterApiUrl } from "@solana/web3.js";
```

And this is the bug:

```
Module parse failed: Unexpected token (14:38)
File was processed with these loaders:
 * ./node_modules/babel-loader/lib/index.js
You may need an additional loader to handle the result of these loaders.
| function getUserAgent() {
|   if (_userAgent === undefined) {
>     _userAgent = globalThis.navigator?.userAgent ?? null;
|   }
|
```

Comment: Can you provide some more information maybe some screenshots of what you are trying to do.

Comment: are you using webpack?

Comment: I was just following this tutorial
https://docs.cloud.coinbase.com/wallet-sdk/docs/solana-adapter-guide

Comment: I've voted to close this question; it's not about Solana so much as it's a JavaScript build system problem that's probably better addressed by Coinbase (ie. by updating their tutorial).